# Обращение на LocalHost Table MySQL через Phython c общедоступного сервера

Tags: python, mysql, flask, клиент-сервер

При `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` с другого компьютера можно зайти на HTML страницу.
Но не получается обращение таблице MySQL находящейся на локальном сервере

Comment: Какое отношение flask имеет к mysql?

Comment: Flask работает между Python и HTML. A Python получает данные из HTML с помощъю FLASK что бы занести на МУSQL. Через общедоступную сеть открывается HTML но обращения на MYSQL  не получается у меня.  Спасибо!       app.run(host='0.0.0.0')

Comment: покажите реализацию вашего подключения в СУБД, зачем нам запуск приложения если проблема в БД ?)